# how to dismiss keyboard of custom textfield in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created uitextfield as a subview of uiimageview & both textfield and uiimageview are subview of scrollview. what is the way to hide the keyboard while editing the textfield.
here my codes , its not working.

```
{
   img1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 320, 60)];
   img1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   NSString *imgfilepath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"123" ofType:@"png"];
   UIImage *imo=[[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:imgfilepath];
   [img1 setImage:imo];

   UILabel *label1;
   label1=[[UILabel alloc]init];
   label1.frame=CGRectMake(60, 0, 250, 30);
   label1.text=@"ENTER ANNUAL INCOME";
   label1.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   label1.font=[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:16.0f];

   label1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   [img1 addSubview:label1];


   principal = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85,30, 156, 40)];
   principal.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   principal.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
   principal.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
   principal.placeholder=@"ENTER";
   [principal setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
   //principal.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;

   [img1 addSubview:principal];

   [img1 respondsToSelector:[principal resignFirstResponder]];

   [scrollview addSubview:img1];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [principal resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: What class are these methods in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[img1 respondsToSelector:[principal resignFirstResponder]];`

First of all, `respondsToSelector` returns a `BOOL` which you use to determine if you can call a selector. This is not a `void` method, it appears that you have misunderstood that.

Second, `UIImageView` does not respond to `resignFirstResponder`.

Third, you are "passing in" `void` to `respondsToSelector:`, which I am surprised compiles?

Ultimately what you want to do is call `resignFirstResponder` on your `UITextField` which would be achieved by calling `[principal resignFirstResponder]`.

But, one of the easiest ways to dismiss the keyboard is by calling `[self.view endEditing:YES]` which is described to do ...

> Causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to resign the first responder status.